# Unity Custom materials are all black on one computer, not the other

Tags: unity-game-engine

On my computer everything looks fine, but on my laptop specific materials are all black. I've made sure i'm on the same version of the project. It is also black in the build.

I am using the customizableGrid from the asset store.

[image]

Comment: Are you using custom or non standard shader on the material? I see that you are using customizableGrid shader from the M_Grid_053 material. The shader is not compatible on the other computer. Contact the publisher. We can't help you without the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before, and for me it was related to lighting. It's a bit difficult to know if you're in the same position based on just the screenshot, but try - on your laptop - going into Window -> Lighting -> Settings and press "Generate Lighting" again. Could be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works, but I'll post it anyway. For anyone else having the same issue this might work. Upload it to the collab cloud. Delete from disk, redownload from cloud. I've had the issue three times now, and everytime i redownload it from the cloud the textures are back. It is a weird glitch indeed, but at least I have a workaround.